# Fancybox in Laravel foreach loop won't pop-up. opens new tab instead

Tags: php, laravel, fancybox

For a photo page I'm trying to show all photo's in the directory. I have a page with fancybox which works great but on another page where I'm using a foreach loop it's not opening in fancybox but just opens it in the browser.

```
 @foreach($images as $image)

     <article class="portfolio-item isotope-item isotope-design wow flipInY" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay="0.25s">

          <div class="portfolio-item-container">

              <div class="portfolio-item-media">
                  <a href="{{asset($image)}}" title="{{basename($image)}}" 
                     class="overlay-hover-2x scale-hover" data-gfort-lightbox>
                      <img style="height: 260px;" src="{{asset($image)}}" alt="Article Image"/>
                  </a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </article>
 @endforeach
```

I'd like to know how to fix this. I think it has something to do with the `href` but I can't put my finger on it.

Any help is appreciated thanks in advance

dd of an image

```
-relativePath: ""
-relativePathname: "Breda 1.jpg"
path: "images\fotos\Breda"
filename: "Breda 1.jpg"
basename: "Breda 1.jpg"
pathname: "images\fotos\Breda\Breda 1.jpg"
extension: "jpg"
realPath: "C:\xampp\htdocs\MRensen\blog\public\images\fotos\Breda\Breda 1.jpg"
aTime: 2017-11-13 22:24:08
mTime: 2017-11-13 22:24:08
cTime: 2017-11-13 22:24:08
inode: 0
size: 2876361
perms: 0100666
owner: 0
group: 0
type: "file"
writable: true
readable: true
executable: false
file: true
dir: false
link: false
linkTarget: "C:\xampp\htdocs\MRensen\blog\public\images\fotos\Breda\Breda 1.jpg"
```

Comment: What is the output of {{asset($image)}} ? Maybe you need to replace data-gfort-lightbox with data-fancybox?

Comment: added the dd on question. but this is only one image. the next loop its a different one

Comment: If you want to create a gallery, add `data-fancybox="images"`.